# JavaFX 15 Libraries not working with Java 14 in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, ide, libraries

I had this working before, and I am 99% positive I have been following the same procedure I have used in the past of adding the lib to the project file structure, adding VM options in the Edit Configurations menu. For some reason I still cannot get JavaFX to work with my setup the way it did in the past. My old projects still run and were written with the same libraries and Java version. I have been banging my head on the wall with this issue all morning, I feel as though the solution may be sitting right in front of me. I have no clue what else to try from here, Reddit has been useless and everything I've searched has been the same.

I have tried running with both, when I took the VM options out the last time I finally got my errors in the editor to go away, but get the errors I had in the original post, this is why I didn't include them in the ZIP but included them in the post.

https://ufile.io/6iknpzqy

**I have tried with these VM options and without**:

--module-path /home/(myUser)/Downloads/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x34ce8af7) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x34ce8af7
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
    at DoMath.start(DoMath.java:36)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run$$$capture(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application DoMath
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51735', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is this a modular project? How are you running it?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The source file is not enough. Zip and share the project directory with all the IDE project files.

Comment: JavaFX requires a lot of additional configuration per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#create-project which we cannot guess from your question. Did you add the VM Options? How do they look like?

Comment: Where did you specify it? The project zip you linked doesn't have these options in the Run configuration.

Comment: I have tried running with both, when I took the VM options out the last time I finally got my errors in the editor to go away, but get the errors I had in the original post, this is why I didn't include them in the ZIP but included them in the post.

Comment: Make sure the options were added to the [VM Options](https://i.imgur.com/uiSj4Ny.png). And not to the Program arguments. Please see [this correct screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Jxo7C1c.png). Notice that command arguments field is empty and VM Options field is used. Your project is also using JDK 14, so you may need to add `--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism=ALL-UNNAMED` per the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this got it working, for some reason the documentation I had a link to in the past did not have the extra options, knew it had to be something stupid simple.

Comment: That error can only mean that `javafx.controls` is not being resolved as a module, but the classes in that module can still be found on the class-path. You mention you used `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` but I would double check. Also, it may be easier to make your code modular and simply add the necessary `requires` directives.

Comment: _I have tried with these VM options and without_ random trying is not the best approach to understand what's going wrong ;) Better would be to work through a tutorial on modularized javafx and try to understand what these options mean.

Answer (score 1):

Your project is using Java 14, even though you initially specified Java 11 in the question.

Per [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) when using Java 14 the following VM Options are also needed:

```
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism=ALL-UNNAMED
```

in addition to these options:

```
--module-path /home/(myUser)/Downloads/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Double check all the options are specified in the [VM Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wYAe.png) field of the Run Configuration, not in the Program Arguments.

[image: VM Options]

Comment: interesting .. wondering why the extra add-exports? can't remember any particular change in fx14 (vs. earlier modulized versions) - but then, I tend to keep my dev machine unchanged as long as possible <g>